# JSON second level child to HTML

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON like below...

```
"title": Here is the Title,
"production_countries": [
    {
        "name": "United States of America"
    }
```

I can grab the parent values like this...

```
let title = document.getElementById("title");
    title.innerHTML = out.title;
```

But I don't know how to access the child values.
In my above JSON example, what JS can I use to get the 'production_countries' 'name' value?

Comment: `out.production_countries[0].name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON, `production_countries` is an array of objects. So when you access it from Javascript it will be rendered as an array.
So you will have to access `name` as below.

```
out.production_countries[0].name
```